# How do I learn about RFID families

Tags: rfid, tutorial, parallax, information

I recently got a parallax RFID reader. [The documentation](https://www.parallax.com/sites/default/files/downloads/28140-28340-RFID-Reader-Documentation-v2.4.pdf) says that it only works with the EM4100 family of RFID tags. So I tried looking it up and can’t seem to find any sort of resource explaining what different families are and what they are used for. One thing I was hoping was to find what hotel keys use so I could make use of some old ones I have lying around. In any case, I just can’t seem to find any good information online, so I was hoping someone here could help.